# Regex match multiple numbers after keywords

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a question about writing Regex under Python.

The string is:

```
abc rules 2.3, 4.5, 6.7, 8.9 and def rules 3.6, 6.7, 8.9 and 10.11.
```

My goal is to try to use a one line regular expression to capture all the numbers.

Moreover, I want to put the number into different groups. `2.3, 4.5, 6.7, 8.9` should be under group `abc rules` and `3.6, 6.7, 8.9 and 10.11` will be under `def rules`.

I have try to use the regex:
`(?<=abc rules) \d{1,2}.\d{1,2}` to capture all the numbers after abc rules, but I could only get the first numbers.

How can I achieve the goal?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: It doesn't know to keep going after the `, `s. You could do something like, `(?:\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}(?:, )?)+` then maybe split on the `, ` to get each individual reference.

Comment: `(?<=abc rules) \d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}(?:(?:,| and) \d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})*`

Comment: `(?<=def rules) \d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}(?:(?:\,| and|, and) \d{1,2}\.\d{1,2})*` this works for def rules as well. Thank you sln and chris85!

Comment: @YichengWang: I do not think a one liner regex solutions are a good idea for such complex requirements for Python `re`. Look, you may use [`\b(?:abc|def)\s+rules\s+(\d*\.*?\d+(?:(?:,|\s*and)\s*\d*\.*?\d+)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/GOqoQL/1) (already a complex pattern) and once a match is found, you may split with `\s*(?:,|\band\b)\s*`, see [this Python demo](http://ideone.com/pz2MFa). Well, `print([re.split(r'\s*(?:,|\band\b)\s*', x) for x in re.findall(rx, s)])` is a kind of a one liner, too :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks man! You are right, one line regex is not the best way to approach the problem.

Comment: Does my solution work? Shall I post for you to accept as a solution?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `rx` and `s` in `re.findall(rx, s)` represent the regex pattern and the string right?

Comment: Yes, and BTW [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) is well documented.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
import re
rx = r"\b(?:abc|def)\s+rules\s+(\d*\.*?\d+(?:(?:,|\s*and)\s*\d*\.*?\d+)*)"
s = "abc rules 2.3, 4.5, 6.7, 8.9 and def rules 3.6, 6.7, 8.9 and 10.11."
print([re.split(r'\s*(?:,|\band\b)\s*', x) for x in re.findall(rx, s)])
# => [['2.3', '4.5', '6.7', '8.9'], ['3.6', '6.7', '8.9', '10.11']]
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/pz2MFa)

The point is, you may match the substrings with numbers, capture the number only parts, and then split those latter ones with `\s*(?:,|\band\b)\s*` regex.

This matches all the substrings:

```
\b(?:abc|def)\s+rules\s+(\d*\.*?\d+(?:(?:,|\s*and)\s*\d*\.*?‌​\d+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GOqoQL/1)

**Details**:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:abc|def)` - either `abc` or `def`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `rules` - a substring `rules`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(\d*\.*?\d+(?:(?:,|\s*and)\s*\d*\.*?‌​\d+)*)` - Group 1 capturing:

  - `\d*\.*?\d+` - an int or float number
  - `(?:(?:,|\s*and)\s*\d*\.*?‌​\d+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `(?:,|\s*and)` - `,` or 0+ whitespaces and then `and`
    - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
    - `\d*\.*?‌​\d+` -  an int or float number

The `\s*(?:,|\band\b)\s*` regex matches a comma or a whole word `and` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces.